# MKDirectionsRequest between 2 given points on the map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have the following code that always returns me "Cannot determine route" (or something similar, message varies)

```
   -(void)getPathDirections:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)source withDestination:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)destination{

MKPlacemark *placemarkSrc = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:source addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *mapItemSrc = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemarkSrc];
MKPlacemark *placemarkDest = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:destination addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *mapItemDest = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemarkDest];
[mapItemSrc setName:@"name1"];
[mapItemDest setName:@"name2"];

MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
[request setSource:mapItemSrc];
[request setDestination:mapItemDest];
[request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile];
request.requestsAlternateRoutes = NO;

MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         // Handle Error
     } else {
         [_mapView removeOverlays:_mapView.overlays];
         [self showRoute:response];
     }
 }];

}
```

I am in Romania, and my country is on the Apple list with route-supported countries.

Also I am able to do a route between my current position, and a marker on the map...

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a valid coordinates when creating your mapItem. Code looks fine to me. Should be something with the coordinates passed to your method. Put NSLog on the coordinates and check them

Comment: @PanayotPanayotov yes, passed coordinates are ok

Comment: So no routes in the response right? Give me the coordinates I'll try here

Comment: @PanayotPanayotov take this for example source = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.51898765563965, 44.26686859130859);
    destination = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.3679256439209, 44.10536575317383); Tho you can use any coordinates... it doesn't matter the country, gives the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works perfect with the coordinates in Europe. The coordinates you gave me in your comment above are in Saudi Arabia, not Romania. Make sure you have a valid coordinates. Easiest way to check your coordinates is going to Google maps and in the search box just place your `Latitude` and `Longitude` values and see where on the map this is.

**P.S**
Your mistake is swapping `Latitude` and `Longitude` values. Change them other way around and check again :)

Instead of this:

```
source =  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.51898765563965, 44.26686859130859); 
destination = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(24.3679256439209, 44.10536575317383);
```

Use this:

```
source =  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(44.26686859130859, 24.51898765563965); 
destination = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(44.10536575317383, 24.3679256439209);
```